# Can I use the expression "go honey nuts"?

Tags: idioms

Someone has replied to my greeting with the expression "honey nuts". What does it mean? I was not able to find it!

Comment: Can you give us more context?  Did they say just "honey nuts" or "go honey nuts"? - your title and post say different things.

Comment: Why not just ask them?

Comment: It sounds like this person is just being cute and said a thing that is particular to them rather than to the English language. But as has been previously stated, without context or clarification there's not much we can tell you.

Comment: I call people I know well and love, silly things -- my daughter got "Love Bug" when she was little. My husband has been known to hear "Darling-Pie"  (I know!) My BFF calls me "Smartie" (It's a Canadian candy, not a reference to my intelligence), and I call her Posey -- a word she tried to spell once a long, long time ago. So we can only guess why she called you Honey Nuts, or if it referenced the cereal, or what she meant by it. Ask her!

Answer (score 1):

"Honey nuts" refers to actual, edible  nuts baked/prepared  with honey, usually eaten as a snack. It can also refer to breakfast foods that contain "honey nuts."

As far as words, "honey" means sweetheart, "nuts" means crazy; "go nuts" means go crazy, literally or figuratively. "Go honey nuts" is a new one to me. You'll have to be more precise in how it was used. It could be the case that the person just likes honey nuts and named this snack when you greeted him or her.

Comment: Or maybe like a cheer, "Go, Honey Nuts!"